# class style is missing when coverts svg to data url as the src of an img element in ie9+

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, styles, data-uri

when I convert svg to data url as the src of an img element in ie9+, the class style declared in style tag is missing, 
[image]
but it works well in chrome. 
[image]
I have been in this problem for a few days, any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Here is [code](https://github.com/momopig/svgToDataUrl) and the [demo](https://momopig.github.io/svgToDataUrl/)

Comment: Why have you not posted an example showing the failure?  Posting the working standalone SVG is not particularly helpful.  Please read this article: [mcve]

Comment: It does not work in ie9+